Querying class members variables with DuckDB
I have a codebase with an API to pass a SQL query to run for execution, but that same API does not provide a way to pass a variable. Meaning I do not get to pass a variable in the same scope as where the query runs:
class SampleClientClass(BaseExecutionAPI):
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = duckdb.DuckDBPyConnection()
    
    def _execute_queries(self):
       qs = self._yield_queries()
       for q in qs:
          self.conn.sql(q)

    def _yield_queries(self):
       ...


I have tried passing it as a class member instead (since I do not get to override or alter the _execute_queries method) but that does not seem to work:
class MyTableCreationClass(BaseExecutionAPI):
    def __init__(self, df: pd.DataFrame):
        self.conn = duckdb.DuckDBPyConnection()
        self.my_df = df
    
    def _execute_queries(self):
       qs = self._yield_queries()
       for q in qs:
          self.conn.sql(q)

    def _yield_queries(self):
        return [
        f"""
        INSERT INTO my_table BY NAME
        SELECT * FROM \"self.my_df\"
        """
        ]

Which gives me the error:
Table with name self.my_df does not exist!
Is there a way to have DuckDB pick up class members at all, or does it only work with local variables?

The issue you're encountering is related to how DuckDB interacts with Python variables and class members. DuckDB doesn't automatically have access to Python variables or class members within SQL queries.
DuckDB provides a from_df function (see here) that allows you to create a temporary table from a pandas DataFrame. You can use this approach to make your DataFrame accessible within the SQL query:
class MyTableCreationClass(BaseExecutionAPI):
    def __init__(self, df: pd.DataFrame):
        self.conn = duckdb.DuckDBPyConnection()
        self.my_df = df
    
    def _execute_queries(self):
        # Create a temporary table from the DataFrame
        self.conn.execute("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_df AS SELECT * FROM self.my_df")

        # Or perhaps this approach:
        # my_df = self.my_df
        # self.conn.execute("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_df AS SELECT * FROM my_df") 

        
        qs = self._yield_queries()
        for q in qs:
            self.conn.sql(q)
        
        # Optionally, drop the temporary table after use
        self.conn.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_df")

    def _yield_queries(self):
        return [
        """
        INSERT INTO my_table BY NAME
        SELECT * FROM temp_df
        """
        ]

In this approach, we create a temporary table temp_df from self.my_df before executing the queries. The SQL query can then reference this temporary table.
Does it work?
